# Error CS1525 "Unexpected Symbol 'end-of-file'"

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I have been trying to troubleshoot this error all day I'm pretty sure a closing parenthesis is required at the end of line 10 but other than that i have no clue besides closing the classes which only led to another error. Here's the code.

```
public class Synthology
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        uint machine_id = 30206;

        bool isMac = false; 

        uint cx=0, c1 = 0x0C6B73ABD, c2 = 0x0E42C2B47, c3 = 0x07C6958DA;
        uint req = ((uint)(isMac ? 0x0000 : 0x6400 )
    }
}
```

Comment: Also please take care to properly format your code when posting - it is very hard to read otherwise.

Comment: Hmm, no.  Golden rule: always fix the **first** error in the Error List.  The ones after that get progressively less reliable.   There was no point in posting code that is missing the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Your line beginning with `uint req ...` has two issues:

- Missing semicolon at the end
- Unmatched parentheses - remove the first one or add another one at the end

When fixed it should look something like this:

```
uint req = (uint)( isMac ? 0x0000 : 0x6400 );
```

Comment: An easier way is: `uint req = isMac ? 0x0000u : 0x6400u;`